# How to create a folder in Team Drive with Google's Python Drive Client API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I don't seem to find many articles on this. The tutorial from Google only shows creating folders in a regular Google Drive folder.

Below is my function and it fails with `oogleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json returned "File not found: myteamdrivefolderid.". Details: "File not found: myteamdrivefolderid.">`

My app is a Python desktop app and has already been authorized to have full Drive read/write scope.

```
def create_folder(service, name, parent_id=None, **kwargs):
    # Create a folder on Drive, returns the newely created folders ID
    body = {
        'name': name,
        'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    }
    if parent_id:
        body['parents'] = [parent_id]
    if 'teamDriveId' in kwargs:
        body['teamDriveId'] = kwargs['teamDriveId']
    folder = service.files().create(body=body).execute()
    return folder['id']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to create new folder in the shared Drive using googleapis for python.
- You have the permission for creating new folder in the shared Drive.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, please add `supportsAllDrives` to the query parameter.
- It seems that `teamDriveId` is deprecated. Please use `driveId`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
body = {
    'name': name,
    'mimeType': "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [parent_id]
if 'teamDriveId' in kwargs:
    body['driveId'] = kwargs['teamDriveId'] # Modified
folder = service.files().create(body=body, supportsAllDrives=True).execute() # Modified
return folder['id']
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)